# Several floating DIVs and the last one filling remaining space

Tags: css, html, space

There are several floating `div`s, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/YyKxB/
How to make the last `div.verylast` filling the remaining space? Of course the width of this space will vary depending on the numer of rows and columns which the `div`s will arrange in the actual window width.

How to do this without JS?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Should the last `<div/>` span all 3 columns in the last line if the window size allows for 3 columns (so the first 9 `<div/>`s are in a 3x3 matrix)?

Comment: Yes. The last `div` should be at least of one column width but when there (in a last row of `div`s) is a remaining space for two columns then it should fill this space. The same for three, four and so up to 100%.

Comment: What you're looking for is very tricky to pull off:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/vgHmd

Comment: Do you mean horizontal or vertical space?

Comment: When floating divs require more than one line to arrange themselves, and .verylast, tries to expand to its maximum available width, it will expand more to the right than the last div arranged in the previous line of floating divs. If that is ok for you then there is a simple solution to the problem

Comment: @cimmanon, oh, just saw your comment right now after spending plenty of time trying to fix the problem. Didn't copy your post, I promise. :-)

Comment: @ArleyM: horizontal of course.

Comment: @Fico: unfortunately it's not ok. It should fill exact remaining size (that's the reason why I set borders to show the real effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a perfect match with `flex`, but I did only come "close" with a fixed width for each item:

```
body > div {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

body > div > div {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 200px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
}

.verylast {
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[Here is the Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rdSqa/)

The problem is, I don't know how to prevent the last item to grow to the full width of the container which is larger than the sum of the columns. Sorry, maybe someone else has an idea.

It does work if you are ok with a flexible width, but I guess that's not what you want. Just have a look at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7EM2/).

However, be aware of the fact that this is brand-new and [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is not good at all.

---

Because there seems not to be a perfect solution (CSS only), I try to go in a hacky direction: Maybe your situation allows using media queries:

```
/* ... other media queries for all the other widths */

@media screen and (max-width: 629px) {
    body > div {
        width: 420px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 419px) {
    body > div {
        width: 210px;
    }
}
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ2hn/) As I said: I know it's hacky, but if no one else can provide a clean solution, maybe hacky is ok. ;-)

Browser compatibility: Media queries have [better support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries), there is also a fallback for old IE.

Comment: Thank you! It's the closest to the real solution. The width of all but last `div` should be fixed so yes - it's still not perfect.

Comment: @friedman, Added a little hack, maybe it's helpful.

Comment: It's really cool. Do you know how it would act in different browsers?

Comment: @friedman, Added browser info to both css features.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to your problem; the key principle is: **float the 2 elements, but don't float the last one, and give it a max-width instead.**

http://jsbin.com/aqugok/2/edit

Code for reference:
The HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="floated"></div>
    <div class="floated"></div>
    <div id="fill_remaining_space">This div fills remaining space</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
.floated {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
#container {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 106px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#fill_remaining_space {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

**EDIT:** However, this solution only works for one-line arrangement, and will still make the last div fill 100% (so any background/ border styles of the very last div will be visible underneath the 2 floated ones as well.

Comment: Nice but it does not works when floting divs need more than one line to arrange themselves.

Comment: Ah I suppose that was the solution you were referring to in your comment? Yes, didn't see that. For a multiline solution, one could just copy the container though...

Comment: But you never know how many lines the client will get according to his window width. Sorry but it doesn't work yet.

Answer (score -1):

This solution will expand last div to the maximum available remaining width 
You need to apply the same trick used for similar columns height

```
div.verylast {
    padding-right:2000px;
    margin-right:-2000px;
}
```

Use an exaggerated padding to the right and compensate it with a negative margin
See it working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/LZVFc/)

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. The last `div` is huge but does not fill the remaining space in the right way. It just extends the whole page to 2000px.